# Unity Shooting script delay not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, delay, unityscript

I am making a shooter game in Unity. I wanted to delay the shooting script but now my code doesn't seem to be working. Any clues to how I might solve this? Other than the delay function everything worked fine.

Here is the code:

```
    #pragma strict

private var player          : GameObject;
public  var speed           : float;
private var bulletCounter   : int;
var reloadtime : float = 2; 
private var reloadTimer: float = 0.0;

function Start () {
    player = this.gameObject;
}

function Update () {
    if (reloadTimer > 0){ 
        reloadTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (reloadTimer <= 0){ 
            if(Input.GetKey("space")) {
                Shoot();
            }
        }

        if(Input.GetKey("w")){
            if(player.transform.position.y < 20) {
                player.transform.position.y += speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
        if(Input.GetKey("s")){
            if(player.transform.position.y > -20) {
                player.transform.position.y -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
        if(Input.GetKey("a")){
            if(player.transform.position.x > -20) {
                player.transform.position.x -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
        if(Input.GetKey("d")){
            if(player.transform.position.x < 20) {
                player.transform.position.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }

    }
    function Shoot () {
        bulletCounter++;
        var bullet = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        bullet.transform.position = player.transform.position;
        bullet.AddComponent.<BulletScript>();
        bullet.name = "Bullet"+bulletCounter.ToString();
        var audio : AudioSource = GetComponent.<AudioSource>();
        audio.Play(); 
        reloadTimer = reloadtime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good question! I have the same problem with my Spacebear project and I hope you get a amazing solution!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get movement code(W,S,A,D) outside the timer condition -

```
#pragma strict
private var player          : GameObject;
public  var speed           : float;
private var bulletCounter   : int;
var reloadtime : float = 2; 
private var reloadTimer: float = 0.0;
function Start () {
    player = this.gameObject;
}
function Update () {
    if (reloadTimer > 0){ 
        reloadTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (reloadTimer <= 0){ 
            if(Input.GetKey("space")) {
                Shoot();
            }
        }
    }
    /********* Move this outside the timer condition *********/
    if(Input.GetKey("w")){
        if(player.transform.position.y < 20) {
            player.transform.position.y += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
    if(Input.GetKey("s")){
        if(player.transform.position.y > -20) {
            player.transform.position.y -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
    if(Input.GetKey("a")){
        if(player.transform.position.x > -20) {
            player.transform.position.x -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
    if(Input.GetKey("d")){
        if(player.transform.position.x < 20) {
            player.transform.position.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
    function Shoot () {
        bulletCounter++;
        var bullet = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        bullet.transform.position = player.transform.position;
        bullet.AddComponent.<BulletScript>();
        bullet.name = "Bullet"+bulletCounter.ToString();
        var audio : AudioSource = GetComponent.<AudioSource>();
        audio.Play(); 
        reloadTimer = reloadtime;
    }
}
```

This will keep the movement enabled during wait period(reloadtime) after player shoots.

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea is not so clear. Easiest way to do it would be.

```
function Shoot () {
    ... 
    reloadTimer = Time.time + reloadtime;
}
```

And if should look like this

```
    if (reloadTimer >= Time.time){ 
        if(Input.GetKey("space")) {
            Shoot();
        }
    }
```